# Jquery conflicting with Javascript for GMaps API? How can I resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help answer why the jquery won't work below?

Is there some sort of conflict between the javascript I'm using for the google maps and the jquery? How can I get it so they are working correctly?  I'm pretty sure I've referenced everything right in the html.

```
function initialize() {
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(9.9333, -84.0833),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.4714, -84.6454),
        new google.maps.LatLng(10.3143, -84.8250),
        new google.maps.LatLng(9.8833,  -85.5333),
        new google.maps.LatLng(9.6500,  -85.0667),
        new google.maps.LatLng(9.4319,  -84.1615),
        new google.maps.LatLng(9.9333, -84.0833)
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: 'blue',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center); 
        document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.height = (h*0.4)+"px";
        document.getElementById('wrapper2').style.maxHeight = (h-15)+"px";
        document.getElementById('info').style.maxHeight = (h-(h*0.4)-15)+"px";
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('photos').hide();

});
```

Comment: What _won't work_? Anyways `photos` is not a valid HTML tag, it should be `.photos` with all chance [a class selector].

Comment: It is an ID, but you're right, I'd not put a # in there! thank you :)